# How to modify AOSP to run a bash script on device boot?

Tags: android, android-service, android-source, android-build

How can AOSP be modified to run a bash script on device boot? Which directory should the script be placed in and what defines the order that the scripts are run? Would any permissions need to be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step-1: Create a .sh file and put it under vendor/

Step-2: Create Android.mk with block

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE       := script.sh
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS  := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := EXECUTABLES
LOCAL_SRC_FILES    := $(LOCAL_MODULE)
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH  := $(TARGET_OUT_VENDOR_EXECUTABLES)
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Step-3: Put entry in root mk

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += script.sh
```